# How to fix text fields and buttons programatically in all iphone inches using with autolayouts

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am a beginner in iOS and in my project i have to apply auto-layouts programatically but here all fields width is not suitable for all iPhone inches in iPhone 4@5 inches it's ok but i phone 6 inch width is not suitable for all fields as like 4@5 and according to my code screen is coming like first image but i want to fix that all fields as like second screen i mean all fields have to suitable for all i phone inches please help me some-one and my code is below[image]

```
myView = [UIview new];
        myview .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        myview .backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.47 blue:0.48 alpha:1.0];
        [self.view myView ];


textfield1= [UITextField new];
        textfield1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        textfield1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.47 blue:0.48 alpha:1.0];
        [self.view textfield1];


     textfield2= [UITextField new];
        textfield2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        textfield2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.47 blue:0.48 alpha:1.0];
        [self.view textfield2];

  textfield3= [UITextField new];
        textfield3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        textfield3.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.47 blue:0.48 alpha:1.0];
        [self.view textfield3];


 pickbutton = [UIButton new];
        pickbutton .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        pickbutton .backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.47 blue:0.48 alpha:1.0];
        [self.view pickbutton];




 Submit= [UIButton new];
        Submit.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        Submit.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.47 blue:0.48 alpha:1.0];
        [self.view Submit];


     Clear= [Clearnew];
        Clear.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        Clear.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.47 blue:0.48 alpha:1.0];
        [self.view Clear];


//Applying autolayouts for MyView

        NSLayoutConstraint * constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:300.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:460.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];


        //Applying autolayouts for textfield1
        NSLayoutConstraint * constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfield1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

        constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

        constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:300.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

        constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];


     //Applying autolayouts for textfield2
        NSLayoutConstraint * constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfield2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:60.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:300.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint2];


  NSLayoutConstraint * constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfield2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:60.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:300.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint2];

//Applying auto layouts for textfield3

  NSLayoutConstraint * constraint11 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textfield3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint11];

        constraint11 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:80.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint11];

        constraint11 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:300.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint11];

        constraint11 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint11];


     //Applying autolayouts for pickerbutton
        NSLayoutConstraint * constraint22 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pickerbutton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:100.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint22];

        constraint22 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pickerbutton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:80.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint22];

        constraint22 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pickerbutton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:80.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint22];

        constraint22 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pickerbutton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint22];


     //Applying autolayouts for clearButton
        NSLayoutConstraint * constraint4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:Clear attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:207.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint4];

        constraint4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:Clear attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:100.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint4];

        constraint4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:Clear attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:133.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint4];

        constraint4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:Clear attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: myView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint4];
```

[image]

Comment: Your Swift code looks an awful lot like Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

With "myView", you shouldn't set absolute size. 
Here is example for your "myView":

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:166.0/255.0 blue:224.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
NSDictionary *viewDic = @{@"myView": myView};
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"vSpacing":@10, @"hSpacing":@10};
NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-vSpacing-[myView]-vSpacing-|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:metrics
                                                                              views:viewDic];
NSArray *constraint_POS_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-hSpacing-[myView]-hSpacing-|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:metrics
                                                                              views:viewDic];
[self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];
[self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_H];
```

Result: 
[image]

Comment: If you don't mind can you add remaining fields on myview and post that code please then i would be great full to you